# Post marcada como duplicada, porém não necessáriamente semelhante

Tags: debate, perguntas-duplicadas

O post foi marcado como duplicado, porém aquele post envolve estrutura HTML, algo que não quero fazer misturar com outro post para não ficar muito grande.

[E-mail cai na caixa de spam PHP usando layout HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65198/e-mail-cai-na-caixa-de-spam-php-usando-layout-html)

Aquele post não foi feito para ser uma enciclopédia de como fazer um e-mail marketing mas sim para ter uma boa base de como começar, é impossível colocar tudo sobre como evitar spam.

É o mesmo de ter uma pergunta como fazer um query em mysql e outra perguntando como faz um inner joing. (totalmente diferentes, porém no mesmo assunto)

A outra pergunta é totalmente teórica.

Answer (score 4):

> Antes de mais nada, eu queria dizer que acho muito legal você ter
>   postado esta pergunta no Meta. O Meta serve pra isso mesmo, pra
>   discutirmos o conteúdo do site. E você faz muito bem em defender o que
>   acha justo ou não compreende.
>
> Além disso, saiba por favor que ninguém vota "contra" você ou a sua
>   pergunta. A ideia é simplesmente manter a qualidade do conteúdo no
>   site (eu, nesse caso, estava argumentando que uma pergunta só seria
>   suficiente para solucionar a sua dúvida - talvez eu tenha entendido a
>   segunda dúvida de forma errada, não sei). Muita gente já tem votado
>   para reabrir (afinal, as pessoas têm julgamentos diferentes), então
>   qualquer decisão sempre é reversível. Faz parte do processo, ok? :)

Bom, eu fui um dos que votou como duplicado porque pra mim a pergunta parece duplicada uma vez que o problema é *essencialmente* o mesmo: **você está construindo um sistema de email marketing e deseja descobrir uma forma de evitar que as suas mensagens sejam encaminhadas para a caixa de SPAM.**

Na sua segunda pergunta descobriu-se que um problema/erro/má prática era o formato HTML utilizado. Ótimo! Fico realmente (sem ironia alguma) feliz que isso esteja solucionado. Mas você argumenta que esse assunto é diferente do da primeira pergunta, e eu acho que não é.

Primeiramente, esse tipo de "dica" (sobre como minimizar a complexidade da estrutura HTML) é parte fundamental da "teoria" que você diz solicitar na primeira pergunta. Afinal, seria uma informação importantíssima para um eventual leitor que chegasse lá, só interessado "na teoria". Em segundo lugar, você pode ter solucionado uma dificuldade pontual sua (com o servidor da sua empresa, se eu bem me lembro de comentários - que foram apagados, creio eu) na segunda pergunta, mas o fato de ter melhorado a sua estrutura HTML *não garante de forma alguma* que suas mensagens jamais sejam encaminhadas para a caixa de SPAM novamente.

Vários colegas argumentaram isso em ambas as perguntas, provavelmente porque não entenderam qual era a sua real intenção. Talvez a sua intenção na segunda pergunta fosse mais no sentido de "eu só quero resolver esse problema do email não chegar no servidor da minha empresa, não garantir mais nada". Porém, não era essa a percepção inicial (é só verificar [nas suas revisões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/65198/revisions) que o seu título original, antes da pergunta ser fechada como duplicada, continha "como não cair na caixa de SPAM", bem próximo à sua intenção da primeira pergunta).

Enfim, por favor, não se ofenda com esse comentário, mas talvez uma dificuldade importante esteja na forma como você comunica as suas dúvidas ou responde aos comentários que lhe são efetuados. Outra dica que eu lhe dei (mas, novamente, acho que o comentário foi excluído) é que você não precisa ter pressa pra aceitar uma resposta. Ninguém é perfeito a ponto de te dar uma resposta definitiva, e muitas vezes (e isso é grande parte da qualidade dos sites do StackExchange, na minha modesta opinião) um bom conteúdo é composto de várias respostas complementares.

Resumindo, pra mim as perguntas são muitíssimo próximas e faria todo o sentido unificar seu conteúdo. Mas essa é só a minha opinião (que eu estou tentando defender aqui). Respeito completamente a sua opinião e a da comunidade (que parece estar reabrindo a sua segunda pergunta). Caso as duas permaneçam abertas, minha única sugestão seria deixar um link mútuo entre elas para facilitar a vida de um eventual leitor futuro. Você mesmo pode fazer isso, por exemplo, editando a segunda pergunta e colocando um link para a primeira.

**P.S.: Eu também já havia comentado isso (comentário aparentemente também apagado - algum moderador sabe se teve algum motivo pra isso?), mas creio que também há muita interseção com esta outra pergunta (que eu só encontrei muito depois de toda essa discussão): [Melhores práticas para envios de emails e evitar spam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14923/melhores-pr%C3%A1ticas-para-envios-de-emails-e-evitar-spam)**

Comment: Concordo que elas estão semelhantes, porém quando eu fiz a pergunta o objetivo era apenas enviar o e-mail e ele não cair na caixa de spam, sem a garantia de que ele um dia poderia virar um spam. 
Porém eu acredito que saiu do foco a pergunta, virou muito teórico e eu apenas queria resolver o problema.

Comment: Tá justamente nessa frase a enorme similaridade das perguntas: "[...] apenas enviar o email e ele não cair na caixa de spam [...]". Não é algo tão simples assim. :)

Comment: Mas eu te entendo. Fazendo um exercício de reflexão (se me permite), se você já tinha esse problema na cabeça, talvez devesse ter feito a segunda pergunta logo de cara (ao invés de ter pedido respostas teóricas mais abrangentes). Além disso (e ai pode ter um pouco de falta de experiência - normal, não fique chateado por isso), a sua segunda pergunta talvez tivesse sido mais efetiva se você tivesse compartilhado o corpo da mensagem (o HTML mesmo) ao invés do código que gera, pois ficaria mais claro que a sua dificuldade/interesse era apenas com a mensagem específica. :)

Comment: Realmente ficaria melhor, mas eu não sabia que o problema era o HTML. Eu achava que era alguma configuração do $headers ou o host que eu utilizava para enviar os e-mails. 

Parece que existe outro tópico falando do layout HTML para e-mails. 

Mas entendo esta preocupação de deixar tudo em um tópico só, fica mais organizado. 

Em questão de spam, é muito complexo este tema. Mas a resolução do meu problema foi bem simples e eu não achava a resolução na outra resposta.

A outra resposta me esclareceu melhor, porém esta foi específica, a diferença entre as postagens era inicialmente o código.

Comment: Mesmo assim. Se fosse um email enviado manualmente mas com o mesmo conteúdo, ele também iria para SPAM (foi o que muitos tentaram te dizer, ao mencionar que a decisão é do lado do cliente). Foi por isso que eu disse da experiência. Talvez se vc tivesse tentado fazer o teste enviando o email você mesmo, teria percebido logo cedo que o problema não era o seu código de geração.

Comment: Eu fiz este teste, porém só tive esta ideia bem depois. Na hora que eu postei estava completamente perdido e não sabia o que eu deveria fazer para consertar, mas passando algumas horas eu percebi que poderia ser o conteúdo html. A questão é que ao invés de eu me concentrar em resolver o código eu tive que deixar claro que as duas perguntas tinha objetivos diferentes. 

Mas realmente a minha pergunta poderia ser respondida no outro tópico, porém acredito que podem existir outras perguntas sobre spam. Todas perguntas de spam vai entrar naquele tópico? É muito abrangente o assunto.

Comment: **Esclarecimento do moderador:** eu excluí a maior parte dos comentários  na pergunta porque eles debatiam se ela era duplicata ou não. Não que o debate tivesse deixado de ser válido após o fechamento, mas ali não era o melhor lugar para aquela discussão (o Meta é). Considerando que o debate ainda estava "quente", eu deveria ter avisado e deixado um link para o meta. Falha minha.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento, @bfavaretto. :)

Comment: Não, Felipe. A ideia não é que todas as perguntas sobre SPAM entrem em um mesmo local. Apenas evitar que a mesma pergunta seja respondida em dois locais diferentes (porque isso gera duplicidade de conteúdo e, principalmente, dificulta a vida de quem busca por uma resposta ou solução). Mesmo o seu exemplo, justíssimo e sobre query e inner join, pode gerar a mesma pergunta duas vezes se elas forem feitas sem cuidado, de forma que a primeira seja sobre como fazer uma query (que requeriria um inner join) e a segunda sobre como fazer um inner join (que seria usado na tal query).

Comment: Se for levado isto em conta, metades destas perguntas podem ser consideradas duplicadas http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=inner+join uma vez que diferem somente em alguns detalhes. 

http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7055/inner-join-n%C3%A3o-retorna-resultado-do-banco

http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7055/inner-join-n%C3%A3o-retorna-resultado-do-banco

Mesmos as perguntas sendo parecidas as respostas são diferentes. É o mesmo caso o meu.

Não acho que vale a pena eu discutir um tópico em que já resolvi. Agora se outra pessoa tiver o mesmo problema que eu se virem para responder.

Comment: O que vocês fizeram foi praticamente isto: Eu perguntei o que é que estava causado o problema e vocês me mandaram para o manual (super educado). 

E ainda disseram que o problema não podia ser testado. Joga o código no seu servidor php, troca as variaveis e testa. Se funcionar só pode ser duas coisas, ou o servidor ou o HTML. Alguns dias eu estava bem perdido sobre envio de e-mails. Eu não sabia responder esta pergunta, mas agora esta bem claro na minha cabeça. O pessoal respondeu sem sequer tentar descobrir o problema ou ter uma resolução válida, virou uma pergunta baseada em opinião.

Comment: Bom, meu caro, realmente parece inútil continuarmos discutindo isso. Mas em sua última mensagem você foi bastante injusto com os demais colegas que só tentaram te ajudar. Se ocorreram mal-entendidos e o resultado final não ficou bom, você certamente também tem uma boa parcela de culpa ai. Repensar essa atitude talvez seja uma boa ideia. Boa sorte.

Comment: Teve muita gente que me ajudou, porém teve alguns usuários que ao invés de tentar me ajudar ficaram discutindo como por exemplo o @SneepS NinjA.

Answer (score 2):

Isso daqui seria um comentário longo, mas ficou grande o suficiente para virar uma resposta.

Concordo com o Luiz, quando respondi a segunda pergunta, eu sequer sabia da existência da primeira. Eis o que havia na pergunta:

> ## E-mail marketing. (como não cair para caixa de spam)
>
> Eu cadastrei três e-mails no meu banco de dados no meu E-mail Marketing. Porém quando eu envio o e-mail ele cai na caixa de spam.
>
> Eu não sei o que devo fazer para não cair como spam.
>
> No caso o conteúdo do e-mail é um html de e-mail marketing. (contendo fotos e conteúdo escrito em html).
>
> No caso o código é bem simples, eu envio de um formulário o HTML e pego por PHP.
>
> O host utilizado para enviar é: http://hostbase.com/
>
> *[Um monte de código em PHP]*

Olhando para o passado, o seu texto original não deixava claro o tipo de resposta que você queria. O que eu imaginei é que você queria saber o que podia ser mudado no código para garantir que o e-mail não ia cair em spam, e isso simplesmente não é possível porque não é assim que a coisa funciona. Há pouca coisa no seu código que iria/vai influenciar isso, pois o principal foco está no que acontece dentro dos provedores de e-mails, no conteúdo do próprio e-mail e na atividade anterior do e-mail que você usa como remetente. Além disso, você não mostrou o que exatamente há no e-mail além de dizer apenas que há um HTML com algumas fotos.

Eu tentei dar [uma resposta elucidando isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/65212/132), inclusive citei sobre a presença de imagens e HTML no e-mail. Bem, acho que você não gostou porque a minha resposta era teórica, e não prática, e ainda tomei um voto negativo de alguém e um outro colega também tomou na resposta dele. Entretanto **não era possível dar uma resposta prática como você queria**, por um motivo muito simples: **o problema não está no código e você não mostrou o conteúdo do que você está enviando.**

[Na sua própria resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/65266/132), você demonstrou como era o HTML e explicou que era complexo demais e tinha que mudar o CSS. Legal, mas como você imaginava que alguém daqui além de você mesmo pudesse saber disso baseando-se apenas no que você postou no corpo da pergunta?

Como resultado, a pergunta não era respondível com as informações que você deu. A [resposta que você aceitou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/65201/132) é basicamente, reutilizar um código já pronto, e embora eu considere uma resposta interessante, isso praticamente não tem relação com o fato da sua mensagem cair em spam ou não, que é o que você perguntou.

Depois, você acrescentou isso na sua pergunta:

> Não quero uma garantia que o e-mail nunca cairá na caixa de spam, mas sim o por que dele está caindo na caixa de spam.
>
> Isto não é uma pergunta de opinião, mas sim de experiência, então se você não tem nenhuma experiência de por que está acontecendo isto, por favor não responda.
>
> Acredito que não fui na claro na pergunta, então resolvi edita-la.
>
> A pergunta é simples. Por que neste código os e-mails caem como spam? O que eu preciso mudar no código para não cair como spam? O problema de cair como spam, pode ser o layout HTML?

Não melhorou muito, pois você ainda não deu as informações sobre o que afinal você está tentando mandar. Mas respondendo as perguntas da última linha, a resposta seria: "O problema não parece estar no código", "provavelmente nada" e "sim". Está prático agora?

O problema é que você direcionou a pergunta de forma a esperar que alguém te apontasse alguma coisa no código, quando na verdade não há nada a ser apontado no código que você forneceu. Portanto, mesmo se a pergunta não devesse ser fechada como duplicata, ainda assim acho que ela poderia ser fechada por outro motivo. Ela poderia ser fechada como "**este é um problema que não pode ser reproduzido**", uma vez que para dar a resposta que você queria, a pessoa que respondesse teria que ter informações que não tinha como adquirir. Ou talvez fechar como "**não é claro o que você está perguntando**", afinal de contas as pessoas que tentaram responder acabaram não entendendo o que você estava perguntando e deram respostas que não satisfazeram a você, e ninguém poderia responder de forma satisfatória exceto você mesmo, por causa das informações que estavam faltando.

Comment: Na verdade tiveram respostas legais até, o que eles fizeram foram o mesmo que você fez [Um monte de código em PHP] o que eu queria era justamente o código php. Tanto que apesar do título estar confuso as tags de procura era HTML PHP e Mysql. 

A descrição foi apenas para ajudar a descobrir o que estava de errado no código. Mas ai você me diz, o código compilou e enviou para o e-mail, o que pode estar dando de errado?

Um monte de fatores que eu coloquei no texto e a maioria somente leu o título e nem se quer olhou o PHP ajudariam a responder a resposta.

Poderia ser o host, o headers ou o html

Comment: O PHP é o principal da questão, logo não pode falar [Um monte de código em PHP], isto seria uma ofensa. Eu não queria mais teorias de como não cair no spam, eu queria saber naquele código por que as mensagens viravam spam. É algo completamente diferente. 

Talvez o título deve ter confundido todos vocês, mas o código php e as tags de procura não poderiam ser esquecida. 

Um problema que não pode ser reproduzido? Claro que pode, eu mesmo testei mudando o $arquivo do código e funcionou.

Não saber responder o problema ou a causa do mesmo não significa que não pode ser reproduzido.

Comment: Não adianta cuspir um monte de teoria e olhar em um código simples e mesmo sabendo toda aquela teoria e não conseguir identificar o problema. Por mais que a teoria seja útil e com ela já dá para resolver o problema pratico, muitas vezes o usuário não consegue identificar qual é o problema. Seria o mesmo de que eu criar um tópico falando como fazer consultas mysql e por existir este tópico não poder postar nenhum outro tópico pois aquele já tem tudo.Só que aquele tópico falta informações, então você faz o que? Pede para a pessoa colocar mais informações em uma pergunta já respondida?

Comment: @FelipeJorge Eu não consigo entender como colocar o texto "[Um monte de código em PHP]" pode ser ofensivo. O que eu quis dizer é você estava pedindo qual era o problema no código, sendo que o problema não estava no código, ao menos não no código que você postou. E embora você quisesse uma resposta prática, o seu problema de fato estava na teoria: o formato do HTML+CSS+imagens fez com que o antispam pensasse que a sua mensagem era spam, e isto não tinha relação nenhuma com o seu código PHP.

Comment: @FelipeJorge Quanto ao fato de não poder ser reproduzido, vou reformular: "não pode ser reproduzido **com as informações que estão presentes no texto da pergunta**". Quanto a colocar mais informações na pergunta depois de respondida, eu nem havia falado nada na pergunta, para mim já era caso encerrado. Foi você que veio aqui no meta questionar a comunidade, e por isso eu postei esta minha resposta com a minha visão e a minha interpretação dos fatos.

Comment: @FelipeJorge E sim, eu olhei o PHP e não vi nada de errado nele, mas não imaginei que você reclamaria pelo fato de o seu código estar (ou pelo menos eu acho que estava) certo ao invés de errado. Basicamente você estava teimando em desprezar a teoria e exigindo que lhe apontassem algo de errado no código, e o que acontecia é que não havia nada de errado no código e o problema estava na teoria.

Comment: A questão não seria erro de compilação, porém um HTML errado poderia sim ser o problema, quando postei as respostas da outra pergunta não respondia meus problemas. Mas o problema poderia ser testado.

Não somente o HTML, como o headers ou o host poderia ser o problema. Acho que o meu erro foi não postar o HTML